# Select last records in sorted groups

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a result from a linq query which is a join between two SQL tables

```
var result1 = db.TABLE1.Join(
    db.TABLE2, 
    p1 => p1.ID, 
    p2 => p2.ID, 
    (p1, p2) => new 
    { 
        Id = p1.ID, 
        Date = p2.DATE, 
        Prop1 = p1.Prop1, 
        Prop2 = p2.Prop2, 
        Prop3 = p2.Prop3, 
        Prop4 = p2.Prop4
    });
```

And then I attempt to group the result by Id and select the rows with the latest dates per Id

```
var result2 = result1.GroupBy(p => p.Id)
    .Select(q => q.OrderBy(p => p.Date).LastOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

But this fails with a

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '<>f__AnonymousTypee'6[System.Decimal,System.Double,System.Nullable'1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable'1[System.Decimal],System.String,System.String] LastOrDefault<>f__AnonymousTypee'6' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." error.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is LINQ to SQL (in the title) instead of Entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Last`/`LastOrDefault` in LINQ to entities queries, since there is no available translation to under laying data source language *(SQL)*. Instead sort the records by descending order and then get the first or default like:

```
q.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).FirstOrDefault()
```